# How to split a string by the first occurrence of the delimiter?

Tags: rust

For instance, I have a file with lines that look like this:

```
KEY1=value1
KEY2=value2
```

Sometimes the value part of the string also contains `=` characters:

```
KEY1=value1=thing1
KEY2=value2=thing2
```

In Python, if I just want the KEY=value pairs then I would do:

```
>>> s = "KEY1=value1=thing1"
>>> key, value = s.split("=", 1)
>>> print(key)
KEY1
>>> print(value)
value1=thing1
```

It doesn't appear obvious to me how to do this in Rust.

Comment: Is this what you want? I'm not super well read on rust but this looks like the ticket. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.splitn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`split_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_once). It returns `Some((before, after))` if the delimiter exists, and `None` if it doesn't.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "KEY1=value1=thing1";
    match s.split_once('=') {
        Some((key, value)) => {
            println!("key: {}", key);
            println!("value: {}", value);
        }
        None => {
            println!("expected a key-value pair");
        }
    }
}
```

```
key: KEY1
value: value1=thing1
```